# How to disable Alt key shortcut for special characters on Laptop numpad

Tags: windows, laptop, keyboard-shortcuts, numpad, alt

Windows 11 laptop, English UK keyboard, it has built in numpad separate from main keyboard.
My numpad has <kbd>HOME</kbd>,<kbd>END</kbd>,<kbd>PGUP</kbd>,<kbd>PGDN</kbd>,<kbd>DEL</kbd> and arrow keys for <kbd>NUMLOCK</kbd> `OFF` input.
However when I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>NUMPAD</kbd> (with <kbd>NUMLOCK</kbd> `ON` or <kbd>NUMLOCK</kbd> `OFF`), I always get a print special character.

E.g.

<kbd>NUMLOCK</kbd> `OFF`: If I try <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>END</kbd>(<kbd>NUMPAD1</kbd>, the laptop sends <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>END</kbd> and prints `☺`.

<kbd>NUMLOCK</kbd> `ON`: If I type <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>NUMPAD1</kbd>, I get `☺`.

It used to be fine, I have no idea what happened.

Does anyone know how to disabled these special characters? At least for <kbd>NUMLOCK</kbd> `OFF`?

Comment: Nothing happened, this is normal - my numpad does exactly the same.